How to see all the topics of an RTD server connection already connected in Ms-Excel?
How to see all the topics of an RTD server connection already connected in Ms-Excel?
I am trying to get other topics to explore from the broker RTD server. They allow to link from their desktop application to excel but do not disclose all the formulas. If someone needs the formula I have got, I can paste it here.
